# Orapki Not Found

Tags: oracle

After installing Oracle Database 21c on a red hat instance with its instantclients (sqlplus, basic and additional tools[datapump etc]) I noticed orapki is missing to configure self signed certificates.

I checked the oracle download page however I didn't notice anything concerning orapki cli to download.